# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "vishaltyagi@gmail.com" (type string) at path "mobile" for model "users"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Register = require('./model/register')
require('./db/conection');
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/' , async(req,res)=>{
    res.send("hello")
    
})
app.get('/search/:key',async(req,res)=>{
    let sKey=req.params.key;
    console.log(typeof(sKey));
    let searchData=await Register.findOne({'$or':[
        {name:sKey},
        {email:sKey},
        {address:sKey},
        {mobile:sKey}
    ]})
    res.send(searchData);
})
app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log("server start");
    console.log(`http://localhost:5000`)

});
```

I am triying to create searching api for getting detail of a particular user by email or mobile number and my code shows this error :UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "vishaltyagi@gmail.com" (type string) at path "mobile" for model "users".

my model file is -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
//const {Schema} = mongoose
const registerSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
name:String,
email:String,
address:String,
mobile:Number,
password:String,
date:{type:Date , default:Date.now}
});
const Register = mongoose.model('users',registerSchema);
module.exports= Register;
```

Comment: The issue is that you are attempting to search a string for a field with a numeric data type.

Answer (score 0):

could you please replace your code-

```
let searchData=await Register.findOne({'$or':[
        {name:sKey},
        {email:sKey},
        {address:sKey},
        {mobile:sKey}
    ]})
```

With my code and lemme know the result-

```
let searchData= await Register.find({email:{$regex:sKey, $options:'i'}})
```

This may works only with email.. but first lemme know the result.. i will help you more..

Comment: if find detail by using a mobile number then

Answer (score 0):

In registerSchema, you have defined the mobile field as Number. So you have to make it a string or detect if the search value is a string or number.
If the value is a number then you can add a custom where condition as given below.

```
let whereCondition = [
    {name:sKey},
    {email:sKey},
    {address:sKey}
];

if(typeof sKey == 'number'){
   whereCondition.push({mobile:sKey});
}

let searchData=await Register.findOne({'$or':[
    whereCondition
]});
```

Comment: but req.params.key got only string data

Comment: In that case you have to use isNaN() function which will return true if value contains alphabet value else it will return false if value is numeric. @sawantyagi